# How should I model a Heroica Banquet hall?

Tags: building, heroica

My son had a great idea for his Heroica game: Convert one of the desks from the Fortraan set into a table with food, and then your Hero could stop there and eat to regain health.

I pointed out that the kitchen already had a table with meat on it (the chicken leg), but we decided that a banquet hall with a long table would be better.

I'm therefore looking for some advice on modelling something similar to the Hogwarts feast but at a Heroica Microfig scale rather than Minifig.

Comment: I can't really see this on a square plate, I'd suggest going for 8x16, table in the middle and paths around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fear I have delusions of grandeur on this one, since this is my starting point:

[image: Heroica Dining Hall 12 x 16]

One table partially built to show the fences underneath. You can also add a third table in the centre, but I felt it would be weird to have only one bank for two tables.

It's too big anyway, isn't it?

Comment: With regards to size, maybe, but if it were on one plate (8x8 I guess) then you could use a few together to make a larger one. I'm also looking for recommendations on decoration - food or just plates ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, I was hungry

Comment: Ok, this is weird. Which Star Wars reference?

Comment: @Joubarc Actually the reference is regarding two different scenes, both with the same phrase, "delusions of grandeur". "A Jedi Knight? Jeez, I'm out of it for a little while, everyone gets delusions of grandeur!" - Han Solo and "I'm standing here in pieces, and you're having delusions of grandeur!" ― C-3PO Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have to admit I didn't intend a reference at all though :-) Maybe you've watched it too much?

Comment: @Joubarc Me? Too much Star Wars? Well, now that I think about it, maybe that's actually quite possible... :P